# Spring-cloud-dataflow: How to default the RabbitMQ binder to create quorum queues

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am playing around with the latest Spring Cloud Dataflow with RabbitMQ as the message broker and have noticed the queues that are created on RabbitMQ from the http-source and log-sink are classic queues.

I have tried adding the following application properties to the stream deployments to have the queues be created as quorum queues, but it just keeps creating them as classic queues.

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.quorum.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.default.quorum.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.quorum.enabled=true
rabbit.default.quorum.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the binding properly directly:

```
--spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.quorum.enabled=true
```

You will also need to set the bindings group property to get a named queue created (anonymous will not work w/ quorum - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2839)